# Sending a date from Swift to Vapor 3

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm having trouble sending a date to Vapor 3 from Swift 5, iOS. Here is the error that I get from Vapor:

```
POST /admin/test Expected date string to be ISO8601-formatted.
```

Here is how I'm creating the date in iOS

```
let today = Date()
        let f = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        f.formatOptions.insert(.withFractionalSeconds)
        let finalDate = f.string(from: today)
```

Here is my Transaction model in iOS

```
final class Transaction: Codable, ReflectedStringConvertible {
        
    var id: Int?
    var date: String
    var amount: Int
    var planeID: Int
    var userID: UUID
    var month: Int
    var year: Int

    init(date: String, amount: Int, planeID: Int, userID: UUID, month: Int, year: Int) {
        self.date = date
        self.amount = amount
        self.planeID = planeID
        self.userID = userID
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
    }
}
```

Here is my vapor API

```
func createHandler (_ req: Request, transaction: Transaction) throws -> Future<Transaction> {
           return transaction.save(on: req)
       }
```

Here's my Transaction model on the vapor side

```
final class Transaction: Codable {
    
    var id: Int?
    var date: Date
    var amount: Int
    var planeID: Plane.ID
    var userID: User.ID
    var month: Int
    var year: Int
    //fixes Swift 5 bug
    typealias Database = PostgreSQLDatabase

    
    init(date: Date, amount: Int, planeID: Plane.ID, userID: User.ID, month: Int = 0, year: Int = 0) {
        self.date = date
        self.amount = amount
        self.planeID = planeID
        self.userID = userID
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Is it that I'm sending a string for the date instead of a date? Thanks very much.

Comment: try without fractional seconds

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had tried it, but it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The answer was to remove the fractionalSeconds

```
let today = Date()
let f = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let finalDate = f.string(from: today)
```